# Posting to DB using django serializers

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am learning django rest framework and I seem to have a problem with my ForeignKey models and serializers. I have two models and two serializers

**Models**

```
class Clients(models.Model):
   client_public_key = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=generate_client_public_key, unique=True)
   client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False)
   client_name_abbr = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True)
   created_by = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=False) #Has to be changed to foreign key
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)

   class Meta:
      ordering = ["client_name"]

class Users(models.Model):
   client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   user_public_key = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default=generate_client_public_key, unique=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
   cell = models.IntegerField( null=True)
   support_department = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
   user_status = models.IntegerField(null=False)
   password_changed = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
   last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
   created_by = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=False) #Has to be changed to foreign key
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)

   class Meta:
      ordering = ["first_name"]
```

**Serializers**

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Clients
        fields =  '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id','client_public_key')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # client = ClientSerializer()
    # client = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        depth = 1
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id','user_public_key')
```

**Posting With**

```
def create_user(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        try:
            queryset = Users.objects.get(email=serializer.data['email'])
            content = {'status_response': 'User Created Successfully'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Users.DoesNotExist:
            content = {'status_response': 'User Not Created'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    content = {'status_response': 'User Already Exist'}
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The problem is when I add depth=1 in my UserSerializer I get **(1048, "Column 'client_id' cannot be null")** error when posting data. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: add the posting code and you need to pass client_id or client instance because its mandatory field

Comment: I have added the view, I am passing in the client instance but  I am now getting **Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `depth=1` and uncomment that

`client = ClientSerializer()`

that'll do the same what `depth=1` does. You can also use `read_only=True` here if you want.

Or if you are using it for create client, In your `Users` model, use `related_name=users`. Now in your `ClientSerializer` use

`users = UserSerializer(read_only=True)`

**Note**: Don't use both, you'll end up getting infinity loop.

> Don't use plural name in your model name. Try to follow conventions.

Comment: Hi Farhad, so I did like you suggested, I am not getting  **Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str.** I already have clients created I am trying to create a user with a foreign key of client.

Comment: You can save your serializer like this `serializer.save(client=client_id)`.

Comment: Still saying the same thing, I think I have to realign my serializers. I think my UserSerializer is trying to create a client upon creating a user which is not what I want. I just want to create a user with a foreign key of the client.